# MongoDB "Writing to log file failed, aborting application"

Tags: database, mongodb

After save about 80G data, mongodb just crash.

`journalctl -u mongod` shows the error message below

```
mongod[4948]: {"t":{"$date":"2022-03-31T10:38:44.089+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4522200, "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"Writing to log file failed, aborting application","attr":{"files":["/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"]}}
mongod[4948]: BACKTRACE: {"backtrace":[{"a":"55C58B1FAF55","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7BF55","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357","s+":"215"},{"a":"55C58B1FDA3A","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7EA3A","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo","s+":"3A"},{"a":"55C58B1B48E2","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E358E2","s":"_ZN5mongo5logv214FileRotateSink7consumeERKN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix11record_viewERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE","s+":"512"},{"a":"55C58B1D1D93","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E52D93","s":"_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix5sinks13unlocked_sinkIN5mongo5logv216CompositeBackendIJNS5_14FileRotateSinkENS5_10RamLogSinkES8_NS5_14UserAssertSinkEEEEE7consumeERKNS1_11record_viewE","s+":"213"},{"a":"55C58B30BF33","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3F8CF33","s":"_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core16push_record_moveERNS1_6recordE","s+":"1D3"},{"a":"55C58B1C2BD9","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E43BD9","s":"_ZN5mongo5logv26detail9doLogImplEiRKNS0_11LogSeverityERKNS0_10LogOptionsENS_10StringDataERKNS0_26TypeErasedAttributeStorageE","s+":"799"},{"a":"55C58B1F7D43","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E78D43","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail18logBacktraceObjectERKNS_7BSONObjEPNS_14StackTraceSinkEb","s+":"4F3"},{"a":"55C58B1FBAF3","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7CAF3","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357","s+":"DB3"},{"a":"55C58B1FD9E9","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7E9E9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"},{"a":"55C58B1F6347","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E77347","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","s+":"D7"},{"a":"55C58B384286","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4005286","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","s+":"6"},{"a":"55C58B418C09","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4099C09","s":"__cxa_call_terminate","s+":"39"},{"a":"55C58B383C75","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4004C75","s":"__gxx_personality_v0","s+":"275"},{"a":"7FD5BA505573","b":"7FD5BA4F5000","o":"10573","s":"_Unwind_GetTextRelBase","s+":"1E03"},{"a":"7FD5BA505AD1","b":"7FD5BA4F5000","o":"10AD1","s":"_Unwind_RaiseException","s+":"2B1"},{"a":"55C58B3843E7","b":"55C58737F000","o":"40053E7","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"37"},{"a":"55C588722ABB","b":"55C58737F000","o":"13A3ABB","s":"_ZN5mongo13error_details23throwExceptionForStatusERKNS_6StatusE","s+":"1FDF"},{"a":"55C588739BB1","b":"55C58737F000","o":"13BABB1","s":"_ZN5mongo21uassertedWithLocationERKNS_6StatusEPKcj","s+":"337"},{"a":"55C5882A99DD","b":"55C58737F000","o":"F2A9DD","s":"_ZN5mongo14FTDCController6doLoopEv.cold.437","s+":"2D"},{"a":"55C588D96A1C","b":"55C58737F000","o":"1A17A1C","s":"_ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJZN5mongo4stdx6threadC4IZNS3_14FTDCController5startEvEUlvE0_JELi0EEET_DpOT0_EUlvE_EEEEE6_M_runEv","s+":"5C"},{"a":"55C58B3A051F","b":"55C58737F000","o":"402151F","s":"execute_native_thread_routine","s+":"F"},{"a":"7FD5BA2DD6DB","b":"7FD5BA2D6000","o":"76DB","s":"start_thread","s+":"DB"},{"a":"7FD5BA00661F","b":"7FD5B9EE5000","o":"12161F","s":"clone","s+":"3F"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"4.15.0-173-generic","version":"#182-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 15:53:46 UTC 2022","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"55C58737F000","elfType":3,"buildId":"DDE3587FBCA9EFB4CB2E3A046C99B6247E65A66B"},{"b":"7FD5BA4F5000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1","elfType":3,"buildId":"679F3AE11120EC7C483BC9295345D836F5C104F7"},{"b":"7FD5BA2D6000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0","elfType":3,"buildId":"8B60B9F8D9A27F2264A0D8E6C0768B3B02C29926"},{"b":"7FD5B9EE5000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"71F0F3074A929E519E85F6A5C03A7D1FD976BFE4"}]}}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1FAF55","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7BF55","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357","s+":"215"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1FDA3A","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7EA3A","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo","s+":"3A"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1B48E2","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E358E2","s":"_ZN5mongo5logv214FileRotateSink7consumeERKN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix11record_viewERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE","s+":"512"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1D1D93","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E52D93","s":"_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix5sinks13unlocked_sinkIN5mongo5logv216CompositeBackendIJNS5_14FileRotateSinkENS5_10RamLogSinkES8_NS5_14UserAssertSinkEEEEE7consumeERKNS1_11record_viewE","s+":"213"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B30BF33","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3F8CF33","s":"_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core16push_record_moveERNS1_6recordE","s+":"1D3"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1C2BD9","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E43BD9","s":"_ZN5mongo5logv26detail9doLogImplEiRKNS0_11LogSeverityERKNS0_10LogOptionsENS_10StringDataERKNS0_26TypeErasedAttributeStorageE","s+":"799"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1F7D43","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E78D43","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail18logBacktraceObjectERKNS_7BSONObjEPNS_14StackTraceSinkEb","s+":"4F3"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1FBAF3","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7CAF3","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357","s+":"DB3"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1FD9E9","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E7E9E9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","s+":"29"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B1F6347","b":"55C58737F000","o":"3E77347","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","s+":"D7"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B384286","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4005286","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","s+":"6"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B418C09","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4099C09","s":"__cxa_call_terminate","s+":"39"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B383C75","b":"55C58737F000","o":"4004C75","s":"__gxx_personality_v0","s+":"275"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"7FD5BA505573","b":"7FD5BA4F5000","o":"10573","s":"_Unwind_GetTextRelBase","s+":"1E03"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"7FD5BA505AD1","b":"7FD5BA4F5000","o":"10AD1","s":"_Unwind_RaiseException","s+":"2B1"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B3843E7","b":"55C58737F000","o":"40053E7","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"37"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C588722ABB","b":"55C58737F000","o":"13A3ABB","s":"_ZN5mongo13error_details23throwExceptionForStatusERKNS_6StatusE","s+":"1FDF"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C588739BB1","b":"55C58737F000","o":"13BABB1","s":"_ZN5mongo21uassertedWithLocationERKNS_6StatusEPKcj","s+":"337"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C5882A99DD","b":"55C58737F000","o":"F2A9DD","s":"_ZN5mongo14FTDCController6doLoopEv.cold.437","s+":"2D"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C588D96A1C","b":"55C58737F000","o":"1A17A1C","s":"_ZNSt6thread11_State_implINS_8_InvokerISt5tupleIJZN5mongo4stdx6threadC4IZNS3_14FTDCController5startEvEUlvE0_JELi0EEET_DpOT0_EUlvE_EEEEE6_M_runEv","s+":"5C"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"55C58B3A051F","b":"55C58737F000","o":"402151F","s":"execute_native_thread_routine","s+":"F"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"7FD5BA2DD6DB","b":"7FD5BA2D6000","o":"76DB","s":"start_thread","s+":"DB"}
mongod[4948]:   Frame: {"a":"7FD5BA00661F","b":"7FD5B9EE5000","o":"12161F","s":"clone","s+":"3F"}
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The main message should be `Writing to log file failed, aborting application`

But I have found nothing in the Internet, include mongodb github issue and mongodb official forum.

Checked the log file permission, it owned by mongodb.

Checked the disk available size, it still has space.

For now, I can not start mongod service.

Does anyone have similar experience?

Answer (score 2):

Had the issue and solved it by

```
> mongod --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --repair
> chown -R mongodb: /var/{log,lib}/mongodb/
```

OS: ArchLinux
MongoDB version 4.44

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `mongod.log` file

`rm -rf /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

then restart the mongod service

`systemctl restart mongod`
in case your app is running you need to rerun it

Comment: Could you justify your advice please? Why removing mongo.log should help? In my case it helped indeed but it does not last long, the problem comes back within 1 minute

Answer (score -1):

you can use bash script to restart cli command.

```
#!/bin/bash
until cli_command
do
    echo "Restarting"
    sleep 2
done
```

Comment: It just try to restart, and didn't solve anything