# Community Edition of MongoDB v5.0.8 randomly crashing, seems like its from log files getting too full but not sure

Tags: mongodb, systemd

```
$ mongod --version
db version v5.0.8
Build Info: {
    "version": "5.0.8",
    "gitVersion": "c87e1c23421bf79614baf500fda6622bd90f674e",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "ubuntu2004",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}
```

looking at `sudo journalctl -u mongod` I see an error message related to the log file

```
$ sudo journalctl -u mongod --no-pager
...
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: { "t": { "$date": "2022-11-04T06:35:09.052+00:00" }, "s": "F", "c": "CONTROL", "id": 4522200, "ctx": "conn2980", "msg": "Writing to log file failed, aborting application", "attr": { "files": ["/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"] } }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: BACKTRACE: { "backtrace": [{ "a": "55C6D46E8B25", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3EBFB25", "s": "_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357", "s+": "215" }, { "a": "55C6D46EB60A", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3EC260A", "s": "_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo", "s+": "3A" }, { "a": "55C6D46A25F2", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E795F2", "s": "_ZN5mongo5logv214FileRotateSink7consumeERKN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix11record_viewERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE", "s+": "512" }, { "a": "55C6D46BF963", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E96963", "s": "_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix5sinks13unlocked_sinkIN5mongo5logv216CompositeBackendIJNS5_14FileRotateSinkENS5_10RamLogSinkES8_NS5_14UserAssertSinkEEEEE7consumeERKNS1_11record_viewE", "s+": "213" }, { "a": "55C6D47F9B13", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3FD0B13", "s": "_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core16push_record_moveERNS1_6recordE", "s+": "1D3" }, { "a": "55C6D46B0929", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E87929", "s": "_ZN5mongo5logv26detail9doLogImplEiRKNS0_11LogSeverityERKNS0_10LogOptionsENS_10StringDataERKNS0_26TypeErasedAttributeStorageE", "s+": "799" }, { "a": "55C6D1DF19FB", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15C89FB", "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo21ServiceEntryPointImpl12startSessionESt10shared_ptrINS1_9transport7SessionEEEUlvE2_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data", "s+": "30B" }, { "a": "55C6D1DF9CA9", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D0CA9", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl14cleanupSessionERKNS_6StatusE", "s+": "169" }, { "a": "55C6D16D44C8", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "EAB4C8", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl15scheduleNewLoopENS_6StatusE.cold.860", "s+": "150" }, { "a": "55C6D1DFA144", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D1144", "s": "_ZN5mongo14future_details4callIRZNS_9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl12startNewLoopERKNS_6StatusEEUlS5_E2_EEDaOT_NS_10StatusWithINS0_8FakeVoidEEE", "s+": "34" }, { "a": "55C6D1DFA493", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D1493", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl12startNewLoopERKNS_6StatusE", "s+": "283" }, { "a": "55C6D1DFA8BF", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D18BF", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvNS_6StatusEEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl15scheduleNewLoopES1_EUlS1_E_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEOS1_", "s+": "7F" }, { "a": "55C6D3E98461", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "366F461", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvNS_6StatusEEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous18runOnDataAvailableERKSt10shared_ptrINS5_7SessionEES3_EUlS1_E_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEOS1_", "s+": "41" }, { "a": "55C6D24DB6C3", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "1CB26C3", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport15ServiceExecutor8scheduleENS0_IFvNS_6StatusEEEEEUlvE_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "33" }, { "a": "55C6D3E9861B", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "366F61B", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous12scheduleTaskES2_NS4_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsEEUlvE0_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "BB" }, { "a": "55C6D3E9C4CC", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "36734CC", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_25launchServiceWorkerThreadES2_EUlvE2_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "5C" }, { "a": "55C6D3E9C53C", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "367353C", "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_17runFuncEPv", "s+": "1C" }, { "a": "7EFF34558609", "b": "7EFF34550000", "o": "8609", "s": "start_thread", "s+": "D9" }, { "a": "7EFF3447D163", "b": "7EFF3435E000", "o": "11F163", "s": "clone", "s+": "43" }], "processInfo": { "mongodbVersion": "5.0.8", "gitVersion": "c87e1c23421bf79614baf500fda6622bd90f674e", "compiledModules": [], "uname": { "sysname": "Linux", "release": "5.15.0-1020-aws", "version": "#24~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 2 15:29:13 UTC 2022", "machine": "x86_64" }, "somap": [{ "b": "55C6D0829000", "elfType": 3, "buildId": "927843AEE3DA8ECC011350D41516BD34BF50A46A" }, { "b": "7EFF34550000", "path": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType": 3, "buildId": "F0983025F0E0F327A6DA752FF4FFA675E0BE393F" }, { "b": "7EFF3435E000", "path": "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType": 3, "buildId": "9FDB74E7B217D06C93172A8243F8547F947EE6D1" }] } }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D46E8B25", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3EBFB25", "s": "_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.357", "s+": "215" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D46EB60A", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3EC260A", "s": "_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo", "s+": "3A" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D46A25F2", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E795F2", "s": "_ZN5mongo5logv214FileRotateSink7consumeERKN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix11record_viewERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE", "s+": "512" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D46BF963", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E96963", "s": "_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix5sinks13unlocked_sinkIN5mongo5logv216CompositeBackendIJNS5_14FileRotateSinkENS5_10RamLogSinkES8_NS5_14UserAssertSinkEEEEE7consumeERKNS1_11record_viewE", "s+": "213" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D47F9B13", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3FD0B13", "s": "_ZN5boost3log12v2s_mt_posix4core16push_record_moveERNS1_6recordE", "s+": "1D3" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D46B0929", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "3E87929", "s": "_ZN5mongo5logv26detail9doLogImplEiRKNS0_11LogSeverityERKNS0_10LogOptionsENS_10StringDataERKNS0_26TypeErasedAttributeStorageE", "s+": "799" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D1DF19FB", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15C89FB", "s": "_ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvvEZN5mongo21ServiceEntryPointImpl12startSessionESt10shared_ptrINS1_9transport7SessionEEEUlvE2_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_data", "s+": "30B" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D1DF9CA9", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D0CA9", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl14cleanupSessionERKNS_6StatusE", "s+": "169" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D16D44C8", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "EAB4C8", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl15scheduleNewLoopENS_6StatusE.cold.860", "s+": "150" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D1DFA144", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D1144", "s": "_ZN5mongo14future_details4callIRZNS_9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl12startNewLoopERKNS_6StatusEEUlS5_E2_EEDaOT_NS_10StatusWithINS0_8FakeVoidEEE", "s+": "34" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D1DFA493", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D1493", "s": "_ZN5mongo9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl12startNewLoopERKNS_6StatusE", "s+": "283" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D1DFA8BF", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "15D18BF", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvNS_6StatusEEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport19ServiceStateMachine4Impl15scheduleNewLoopES1_EUlS1_E_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEOS1_", "s+": "7F" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D3E98461", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "366F461", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvNS_6StatusEEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous18runOnDataAvailableERKSt10shared_ptrINS5_7SessionEES3_EUlS1_E_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEOS1_", "s+": "41" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D24DB6C3", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "1CB26C3", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport15ServiceExecutor8scheduleENS0_IFvNS_6StatusEEEEEUlvE_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "33" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D3E9861B", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "366F61B", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_9transport26ServiceExecutorSynchronous12scheduleTaskES2_NS4_15ServiceExecutor13ScheduleFlagsEEUlvE0_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "BB" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D3E9C4CC", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "36734CC", "s": "_ZZN5mongo15unique_functionIFvvEE8makeImplIZNS_25launchServiceWorkerThreadES2_EUlvE2_EEDaOT_EN12SpecificImpl4callEv", "s+": "5C" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "55C6D3E9C53C", "b": "55C6D0829000", "o": "367353C", "s": "_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_17runFuncEPv", "s+": "1C" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "7EFF34558609", "b": "7EFF34550000", "o": "8609", "s": "start_thread", "s+": "D9" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 mongod[115882]: Frame: { "a": "7EFF3447D163", "b": "7EFF3435E000", "o": "11F163", "s": "clone", "s+": "43" }
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code = exited, status = 1 / FAILURE
Nov 04 06: 35: 09 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 04 15: 16: 11 ip - 10 - 3 - 2 - 68 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

running `ncdu /` I can find where the log files are, and I have log rotate turned on

```
--- /var/log/mongodb ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         /..
  175.9 MiB [##########]  mongod.log.1
   96.9 MiB [#####     ]  mongod.log
    6.5 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.7.gz
    5.2 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.3.gz
    4.0 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.2.gz
    3.8 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.4.gz
    3.4 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.6.gz
    3.2 MiB [          ]  mongod.log.5.gz
```

Is there some mystery setting that I can tamper with?

I see the following post but its inconclusive
[MongoDB "Writing to log file failed, aborting application"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71692319/mongodb-writing-to-log-file-failed-aborting-application)

Restarting the application using `sudo systemctl start mongod` gets it to turn back on, but it crashes several days later

Assuming that it crashes because the file is too large, what is the file size cap?

My logrotate settings are listed below

```
/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
{
   rotate 7
   daily
   size 1M
   missingok
   create 0600 mongodb mongodb
   delaycompress
   compress
   sharedscripts
   postrotate
     /bin/kill -SIGUSR1 $(cat /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid)
   endscript
}
```

Its happened 3 times, once October 7, another October 30, and today November 4th

The first two times happened at 6:30PM, and this morning at 6:30AM, both are at times when I have high volumes of data reading and writing to the database, but by no means at any large amount of CPU or memory. Its not abnormal to sit above 90% CPU for pockets of an hour but this took place today when the CPU was below 50%, so not a whole lot of traffic

The hard drive is sitting at 78% full, and it looks like it jumped to 83% full at the time of the crash, then reduced back down.

Is there a setting in MongoDB that kills MongoDB processes it at 80%?

---

Edit: 1

Per request in comments, ran `grep '"s":"[WEF]"' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

```
$ sudo grep '"s":"[WEF]"' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-04T15:16:11.482+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-04T15:16:11.550+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-04T15:16:11.554+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22271,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Detected unclean shutdown - Lock file is not empty","attr":{"lockFile":"/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-04T15:16:11.554+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22302,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-11-04T15:16:12.967+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
```

---

Edit 2:

by request

```
$ ps -lFp $(pidof mongod)
F S UID          PID    PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN    RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
4 S mongodb   138591       1 99  80   0 - 878126 -     1915156 1 15:16 ?        04:56:49 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

```
$ ls -alh /var/log/mongodb
total 317M
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Nov  4 00:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 10 root    syslog  4.0K Nov  4 00:00 ..
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 115M Nov  4 19:13 mongod.log
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 176M Nov  4 00:00 mongod.log.1
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 4.1M Nov  3 00:00 mongod.log.2.gz
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 5.2M Nov  2 00:00 mongod.log.3.gz
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 3.8M Nov  1 00:00 mongod.log.4.gz
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 3.2M Oct 30 18:35 mongod.log.5.gz
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 3.5M Oct 30 00:00 mongod.log.6.gz
-rw-------  1 mongodb mongodb 6.5M Oct 29 00:00 mongod.log.7.gz
```

---

Edit: 3

At this point im about 95% sure that its related to running out of disk memory, looking at my cloudwatch logs I can see many many successful commands executing, then all of a sudden storage events start firing, then immediately after it looks like DB connections dropped and are being re established before a crash

I went to run a manual backup and upload data to our backup server, and in the middle running it the hard drive capped out and ran out of memory even though it reported that it was 78% full, I ended up rebooting and clearing out space to get the DB back on.

Comment: How full is the partition `/var/log/mongodb` is on?  Any related messages is `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs 78%, its on the OS partition

Comment: What does `grep '"s":"[WEF]"' /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` show?  Does `mongod` run under user `mongodb` or `mongod`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs went ahead and added it to the bottom of the OP

Comment: What is `ps -lFp $(pidof mongod)`?  What is `ls -alh /var/log/mongodb`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs updated to end of OP

Comment: Some of the `journalctl` output is truncated on the right margin.  Would you replace that content with the output of `sudo journalctl -u mongod --no-pager`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs no problem, updated

Comment: Is your temporary `_tmp` directory on the same partition as `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`?  Could a "data heavy" query be spilling over to disk reducing space for the log file?

Comment: @rickhg12hs everything is on the same partition, it’s a basic Ubuntu OS running on AWS with no partitions added

Comment: I'm wondering if [Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/index.html) might be useful to monitor/notify/alarm on disk usage.  I also wonder if there is something significant preceding the MongoDB server shutdown that may be reported in `mongod.log`.  Sorry I can't be of more use - this hasn't happened to me (yet).

Comment: @rickhg12hs i've actually been pulling the same thread, im looking at my cloudwatch logs and I see some interesting facts. I am 95% sure that its because it ran out of disk memory even though my cloudwatch graphs are reporting 80% full

Comment: What do people mean by running out of "disk memory"?  Do you mean running out of storage space or something more internal to the disk?  Trying to troubleshooting a random segfault and came across this thread.